# nice name for the image of multivariable function

Tags: multivariable-calculus, terminology

Consider a differentiable function $f:D\subset\mathbb R^m\mapsto \mathbb R^n$ with $m\le n$. I know if $m=1$ then $f(D)$ is called by "path", if $m=2$ then $f(D)$ is called by "surface" and if $m=3$ then $f(D)$ is called by "solid". I wish to know, what is the specific name of $f(D)$ if $m>3$. Is there a literature about this name? I have googled it but I didn't find yet.

Comment: We should be very happy that particular names don't exist, since this would often discourage abstraction.

Comment: @Siminore: Yes, but mathematicians are always curious with the abstractions, aren't they? :D

Comment: You might be interested in reading about manifolds.

Comment: @littleO: Yes, it is related to smooth manifold, isn't it?

Comment: Under certain assumptions on $f$, the set $f(D)$ will be a smooth manifold, which might be the generalization of the idea of a "surface" that you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, more is required. The image of $f$ is $m$-dimensional if the [rank](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank_(differential_topology)) of $f$ is $m$.

About the question, the only other name frequently used is [hypersurface](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypersurface) when the dimension of the image is $n-1$.

Comment: Isn't there any name if the dimension of the image is $m$?

Comment: @Jlamprong, I don't know any beyond the obvious "$m$-dimensional".